# Is Jesus God's apostle?

Tags: john, hebrews

We can read in

> John 3:17 For God did not **send his Son** into the world to condemn the
> world, but in order that the world might be saved through him.

and in Hebrews

> Hebrews 3:1: Therefore, holy brothers, you who share in a heavenly
> calling, consider Jesus, the **apostle** and high priest of our
> confession,

Did God sent his son as an apostle to bear witness of the father?

Comment: The text seems quite straightforward. Can you please [edit] this to explain in detail why you're not sure about it?

Comment: Basic commentaries will clarify. Everyone send by God is an apostle. There are various titles used for Jesus which are considered as offices of Jesus. Servant prophet apostle high priest.

Comment: @curiousdannii I have edit the question if that was not clear.  Jesus have apostles I don't see him as a apostle, so the question is did he apostelship for the father.

Comment: @Michael16 Do you have a commentary you recommend for Hebrew 3:1 ?

Comment: standard commentaries are JFB, Gill, Ellicott; Expositor's & Cambridge. Ushould'v them in your www.theword.net and www.mybible.zone . JFB: "Though the title "Apostle" is nowhere else applied to Christ, it is appropriate here in addressing Hebrews, who used the term of the delegates sent by the high priest to collect the temple tribute from Jews resident in foreign countries, even as Christ was Delegate of the Father to this world far off from Him (Mt 21:37). Hence as what applies to Him, applies also to His people, the Twelve are designated His apostles, even as He is the Father's (Joh 20:21).

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Why does Hebrews 3:1 call Jesus an apostle?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/why-does-hebrews-31-call-jesus-an-apostle)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Hebrews 3:1 call Jesus an apostle?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/why-does-hebrews-31-call-jesus-an-apostle)

Comment: @Michael16 that's a bonafide answer. You would have been welcome to post an answer like that before it got closed. You're ideas are insightful, please consider how valuable your input is in the future. It would have been great.

Comment: @KevinPopov If you can edit this question to provide a little more clarity about what you mean by "apostle" and why you ask this specifically, the question might be able to be re-opened. For example, do you mean "merely an apostle, and not God's son" or do you mean "apostle among other things, to do a similar work as the twelve apostles"? And, what leads you to wonder this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let there be no doubt that the Father sent Jesus, the Son, according to the frequent testimony of the Son:

- John 5:23 - so that all may honor the Son just as they honor the Father. Whoever does not honor the Son does not honor **the Father who sent Him**.
- John 5:37 - And **the Father who sent Me** has Himself testified about Me.
- John 6:44 - No one can come to Me unless the Father who sent Me draws him, and I will raise him up at the last day
- John 6:57 - Just as the living **Father sent Me** and I live because of the Father, so also the one who feeds on Me will live because of Me.
- John 8:16 - But even if I do judge, My judgment is true, because I am not alone; I am with **the Father who sent Me**.
- John 8:18 - I am One who testifies about Myself, and **the Father, who sent Me**, also testifies about Me.”
- John 8:42 - Jesus said to them, “If God were your Father, you would love Me, for I have **come here from God**. I have not come on My own, but **He sent Me**.
- John 12:49 - I have not spoken on My own, but **the Father who sent Me** has commanded Me what to say and how to say it.
- John 17:25 - Righteous **Father**, although the world has not known You, I know You, and they know that **You sent Me**.
- John 20:21 - Again Jesus said to them, “Peace be with you. As **the Father has sent Me**, so also I am sending you.”
- 1 John 4:14 - And we have seen and testify that the **Father has sent His Son** to be the Savior of the world.

... And to confirm this, Jesus, in the book of Hebrews is declared the apostle (= "one who is sent") of God:

- Heb 3:1 - Therefore, holy brothers, who share in the heavenly calling, set your focus on **Jesus, the apostle** and high priest whom we confess.

So what does John 3:17 say?

> For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but
> to save the world through Him.

Note the simple message of this verse is two-fold: to explain what Jesus was sent to do and what He was NOT sent to do, namely

- Jesus was not sent to condemn the world
- Jesus WAS sent to save the world

Thus, Jesus was certainly sent as the Savior of the world and NOT the judge of the world.

Answer (score 3):

The book of Hebrews depicts the risen Christ in the three-fold function of Prophet, Priest, and King (Heb. 1:2-3 & 7:3). He is the only Mediator between God and men (8:6). He intercedes for and saves all who come to God through him (7:24-28). As for Christ being Apostle alongside being Priest, that is also true - Heb. 3:1.

But he is not just one amongst a number of prophets, priests, kings, mediators and apostles. He is our great High Priest. He is King of Kings. He is the only Mediator who enables us to approach God. He chose the apostles who accompanied him during his earthly ministry. The twelve whom Jesus chose were his apostles (Luke 6:13). The relationship is of Christ being The Apostle who chooses men who will be apostles in his Church (Ephesians 4:11). But it's not as if God requires his Son to be ***his*** apostle, as the question seems to put it (unless I've misunderstood.)

The men who were apostles on earth bore witness to Jesus Christ, crucified, resurrected, and coming again from heaven. "You will be MY witnesses..." Jesus commanded them (Acts 1:8). Jesus, on earth, showed them the Father by doing the Father's will, and sharing with the disciples all the words the Father had given him (John 15:15-16). "He that hath seen me hath seen the Father" he explained - not literally of course - see John 14:6-11.

So, Christ is *The* Apostle, just as he is *The* great High Priest, and that for our benefit, not God's. Christ is not Apostle to God, but to those who belong to Christ by faith: "Jesus, the apostle and high priest of ***our*** confession" Heb. 3:1.

You ask, ***"Did God sen[d] his son as an apostle to bear witness of the father?"*** God sent his Son to bear witness of the Father, and all who believed the Son's witness discovered Jesus to be their Apostle, just as he became their King, their Redeemer, their Saviour, their great High Priest and their Mediator.  All the benefits are towards those who make the good confession of faith in Christ. Those thus benefited then become witnesses of Jesus Christ.